# Writing Script for Delphi 7 IDE

Tags: delphi, scripting, delphi-7

Is Delphi have any ability to write script of IDE actions? I would like On open delphi project  execute script opening some unit. How I can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test [cnWizards](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=669&lang=en).
Is an complete IDE Expert that include characteristics for create IDE "expansions" using Scripts.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cnpack.org](http://www.cnpack.org/images/cnwizards.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi IDE cannot be scripted as such, but you can write so-called experts. This is basically a plugin interface for the IDE and you have access to everything under the hood; from adding menu options to replacing event handlers - which I believe is what you're looking for.

Delphi 7 is quite old now, but I reckon much of the [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Extending_the_IDE) is still applicable.